# VSCode editor on macos. Strange behaviour of the multiline selected block

Tags: visual-studio-code

Some time ago I've got a problem with Editor. I select multiple lines (with option-command-<up/down>) and trying to add multiple spaces to shift the whole block to the right. But editor adds tons of extra spaces. Please see screens attached.
Can anyone please help me to bring this to normal state?
Problem has been appeared recently (few days maybe).
VSCode version: 1.46.1
[image: Text has been selected]
[image: The space was pressed]

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It was "**editor.multiCursorMergeOverlapping**". Setting it to true brings the behaviour to default.